# How can I make my dropdown menus stay visible on hover?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, dropdown

I'm not sure why, but my dropdown menus refuse to stay on the screen when hovering over them. They work fine when I make them clickable with `:focus` in the CSS with this:

> .dropdown > .link:focus + .dropdown-menu

But, I want them to work on hover. But when I set it to the following, the dropdown disappears as soon as you take the mouse off the menu header:

> .dropdown > .link:hover + .dropdown-menu

Here is the code on JSFiddle ---> https://jsfiddle.net/L8u96pbr/

What can I change to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dropdown disappears because as you move your cursor from the class `link` to the next sibling with class `dropdown-menu`, it un-hovers the `link`, causing the dropdown to disappear. To fix this, you can add padding to `link`, and if you would like it to take up the same amount of space you can add a negative margin of equal value to the padding (e.g. add `.link { padding: 10px; margin: -10px; }`).

Moreover, your selector `.dropdown > .link:hover + .dropdown-menu` only affects the class `dropdown-menu` when class `link` is hovered. You want this same effect to persist as class `dropdown-menu` is hovered, so add `.dropdown-menu:hover` as well.

```css
.dropdown > .link:hover + .dropdown-menu,
.dropdown-menu:hover {
    opacity: 1; 
    transform: translateY(0px);
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The dropdown disappears because your CSS tells it to show only when you hover on .link which is your about/product link

Instead of this:

```
.dropdown > .link:hover + .dropdown-menu {
opacity: 1;
transform: translateY(0px);
pointer-events: auto;
}
```

Do this:

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
opacity: 1;
transform: translateY(0px);
pointer-events: auto;
}
```

Thank you would fix it